# How to pass PHP variables to a Javascript function

Tags: javascript, php, parameter-passing

I don't understand why the addRow method isn't reading the parameters and I know for a fact they are initialized.

In php
`echo "<script> addRow(".$song.",".$artist."); </script>";`

JavaScript method

```
function addRow(s,a){
        document.write("test");
    }
```

Comment: echo "<script> addRow('".$song."','".$artist."'); </script>";//quote values

Comment: Or for better readability, no need to concatenate: `echo "<script> addRow('$song', '$artist'); </script>";`

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget your quotes!

```
echo "<script> addRow( '".$song."', '".$artist."' ); </script>";
```

Or nicer even:

```
echo "<script> addRow( '{$song}', '{$artist}' ); </script>";
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP

```
<script> addRow('".$song."','".$artist."'); </script>
```

JavaScript

```
function addRow(s,a){
    console.log(s);
    console.log(a);
    document.write("test");
}
```

Comment: im sorry what is the console.log for?

Comment: The JavaScript part is not of particular value.

Comment: console.log is for the display of params, when you try to get them in your function, it is nice to verify it works